# Open descriptors while making a daemon

Tags: c, linux, daemon

R. Love`s book "System programming" in chapter about daemons says:

```
2. In the parent, call exit( ). 
5. Close all file descriptors.
```

Man pages about exit() call says:

```
"The function _exit() terminates the calling process "immediately". Any open file descriptors belonging to the process are closed"
```

Do we really need to close all descriptors in child process, or its just for another safety? Thanks.

Comment: You are not doing these two in the same process!

Comment: Also you should write all points from 2 to 5, so we could show you, why it's in two different processes.

Comment: @zoska, yes, I know, but what the reason of duplicating this operations in exit() and then manually?

Comment: Both happen for to distinct processes? Child gets its parents opened fds, so if it doesn't need them, then it should close them. There's no duplication as both are different processes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe yes, it's better to close all the fds in order to prevent child processes become orphan process if the parent unexpectedly closed.

Comment: what does orphan process have to do with opened fds?

Comment: @zoska I was assuming him using fork() function to create new processes.